# How to extract dates from pandas dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that I created using Pandas:

```
         Name       BirthDay            
0        Alex     1985-01-01
1        John     1977-01-01
2        Rick     1992-01-01
```

I need to create separate lists with values from each column. So I do the following:

```
names = []
birthdays = []
while i < len(df.index):
    name = "".join(df['Name'].iloc[i])
    birthDay= "".join(df['BirthDay'].iloc[i])
    names.append(name)
    bithdays.append(birthDay)
    i += 1
```

The code works fine to populate the first list with names, but it throws this error trying to extract dates:

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

How am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) and for convert datetimes [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) if need convert `datetime`s to `string`s:

```
names = df['Name'].tolist()
print (names)
['Alex', 'John', 'Rick']

birthdays = df['BirthDay'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
print (birthdays)
['1985-01-01', '1977-01-01', '1992-01-01']
```

Alternative solution is cast to `str`:

```
birthdays = df['BirthDay'].astype(str).tolist()
print (birthdays)
['1985-01-01', '1977-01-01', '1992-01-01']
```

---

If need Timestamps (pandas datetimes) in list:

```
birthdays = df['BirthDay'].tolist()
print (birthdays)
[Timestamp('1985-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('1977-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1992-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

And for python dates and datetimes use [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) or [`to_pydatetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html):

```
birthdays = df['BirthDay'].dt.date.tolist()
print (birthdays)
[datetime.date(1985, 1, 1), datetime.date(1977, 1, 1), datetime.date(1992, 1, 1)]

birthdays = df['BirthDay'].dt.to_pydatetime()
print (birthdays)
[datetime.datetime(1985, 1, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(1977, 1, 1, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(1992, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Thanks [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020438/how-to-extract-dates-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python/45020479#comment77015184_45020479) and [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020438/how-to-extract-dates-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python/45020479#comment77015186_45020479) for comments.

Comment: I think the error was `bithdays` instead of `birthdays` but this certainly works!

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use [pandas.Series.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
names = df.Name.values
birthdays = df.BirthDay.astype(str).values
```